# Merge Duplicate Columns

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

On the top column of my report are dates (mm/dd/yyyy) with corresponding data below. When I run the report, it shows multiple columns with the same date but different data. For example

```
5/12/2011 | 5/12/2011 | 6/7/2011
---------------------------------
       10 |         6 |       11
```

How do I merge columns with the same dates while also combining the data as well?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a column group to your tablix on the date field so that it will actually group your dates instead of displaying each one individually. You can then use the SSRS aggregate functions in your details fields to combine the data from the grouped columns & rows.

More info:

- [Understanding Groups (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263.aspx)
- [Aggregate Functions Reference (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255275.aspx)